# Проблема считывания инвентаря Steam в формате json

Tags: php, steam-web-api

При открытии ссылки вида: `http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/steamID/inventory/json/570/2` стим, как я понял, возвращает весь инвентарь определенной игры в формате json. Но при попытке считать всю страницу функцией file_get_contents сайт или виснет, или пишет что слишком большой обьем страницы. Как можно ограничить вывод инвентаря?

Видел пост на эту тему, там советовали в конец добавить GET-запрос вида 
`?l=english&count=5000`, но эти параметры просто игнорируются. ПРошу помочь кто разбирается.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас устаревшая ссылка...
Endpoint такой:

> //steamcommunity.com/inventory/PROFILEID/570/2?count=1000

Параметр `count` определяет размер выборки...
Чтобы получить следующую порцию, добавьте параметр `start_assetid` со значением последнего `asset_id` предыдущей выборки.

Comment: Я изначально искал, как можно посмотреть инвентарь через Steam Web API. Но я там такого не нашел

Comment: ссылка без profiles работает?

Comment: Запрос вида http://steamcommunity.com/inventory/steamid/570/2?l=english работает, только теперь другая проблема) Ограничить количество предметов можно параметром count=xxx, а как потом сделать смещение на следующий промежуток предметов?

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, параметр называется `start`

Comment: Не, не то( Жалко нет хорошей документации

Comment: Нашёл, добавил в ответ

Comment: При добавлении в запрос `&start_assetid=10` выводит {"error":"k_EResultNoMatch (42)"}. Может знак нижнего подчеркивания надо заменить на какой-то код?

Comment: не 10, а **asset_id** из предыдущей выборки. [Пример](http://steamcommunity.com/inventory/76561198051381875/730/2?count=2&start_assetid=11995545598)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68762/discussion-between-bonfire-and-vp-arth).

Comment: Что-то при любом значении параметра start_assetid, отображаются те же самые предметы(